# Using patternproperties for an array of objects whose value is another array in a JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I've been racking my brain trying to get this to work. I have a valid JSON file that I want to run through a schema I'm creating.

Here is a portion of the json I want to validate:

```
{
    "TestProperty":
    [
        {
            "@Array1":
            [
                1.0,
                2.0
            ]
        },
        {
            "@Array2":
            [
                "one",
                "two",
                "three"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the schema I am trying to use:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "title": "TestSchema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "TestProperty" ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties":
    {
        "TestProperty":
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items":
            {
                "oneOf":
                [
                    { "$ref": "#/$defs/TestPropertyObject" }
                ]
            },
            "minItems": 1
        }
    },
    "$defs":
    {
        "TestPropertyObject": 
        {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "patternproperties":
            {
                "^@[A-Za-z]+$":
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items":
                    {
                        "oneOf":
                        [
                            { "type": "string" },
                            { "type": "number"}
                        ]
        
                    },
                    "minItems": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that there can be any number of objects in the `TestProperty` array. Each of those objects must have a property matching the regular expression and the value must be an array. Each of those arrays must either contain all strings or all numbers. Any property that doesn't match the expression is not allowed.

If I explicitly define each property (e.g. `@Array1` and `@Array2`) and move it into `properties` instead of `patternproperties`, my validator is ok with that. However, I won't know these properties beforehand to do that. (It also leads to another issue in that `oneOf` doesn't seem to behave as I want it to) Leaving it as I have above, my validator says that additional properties are not allowed. It seems to me like the pattern matching is not working? Or I have missed something. Is this a limitation of json schemas or my own incompetency?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `^@[A-Za-z]+$` doesn't match `@Array1` or `@Array2`. You need to allow for numbers, such as with `^@[A-Za-z0-9]+$`.

Comment: While that may be true, changing the regular expression to `^@[A-Za-z0-9]+$` did not solve my problem. I get an error "Additional properties are not allowed ('@Array1' was unexpected).

Comment: Then it sounds like you have a bug in your implementation, that you should report to them with a small repro case.